# Python - add dictionaries to list

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

**List 1**

```
[]
```

**dictionary 1**

```
{ 
   'test': 'baum',
   'alter': 0,
   'voegel': ['amsel']
}
```

**dictionary 2**

```
{ 
   'test': 'grosserbaum',
   'alter': 3,
   'voegel': ['meise']
}
```

*Do something to merge dictionaries together....*

**Result:**

```
[
   { 
      'test': 'baum',
      'alter': 0,
      'voegel': ['amsel'] 
   }, 
   { 
      'test': 'grosserbaum',
      'alter': 3,
      'voegel': ['meise']
   }
]
```

How can this be done using Python? Thanks!

Comment: create a list and append two dicts?

Comment: Your requested output throws a `TypeError`. It's not a valid dictionary structure but, rather, an impossible `set()`

Comment: @mad_ Right, I see the data is different. He's looking to make a set of dicts,

Comment: To reiterate/add to @roganjosh 's answer, your question is ambiguous. Are you trying to create a nested dictionary of dict objects, or a set of dicts, or are you trying to combine the values from dict1 and dict2 with the same keys, or maybe a JSON file? What object `type()` do you want to have at the end?

Comment: The result you are showing us is not a dictionary but rather a list of two dictionaries. Keys must be unique and you clearly have repetitions. So you need to think what you want to do in this situation. I would suggest creating a dictionary with the the keys from each dictionary and then for each key in the original dictionaries take the value and insert it into a list. The result will be a dictionary with list values and each list will have the values from both original dictionaries for the same key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d1={ 
   'test': 'baum',
   'alter': 0,
   'voegel': ['amsel']
}
d2={ 
   'test': 'grosserbaum',
   'alter': 3,
   'voegel': ['meise']
}
```

Lets try with your expected output

> {d1:d2} #TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

The error is raised because the `dict` type cannot be hashed. similar to the list type as it does not comes with a hash function. Therefore, moral of the story is in order for an object to be hashable, it must be immutable types like `string`, `integer` or `tuple`.

In case you are just looking to iterate over the dicts

```
[d1,d2] # convert into a list
```

OR

```
(d1,d2)# convert into a tuple
```

or create a new list with immutable keys

```
{'d1':d1,'d2':d2}
```

For further reference https://www.asmeurer.com/blog/posts/what-happens-when-you-mess-with-hashing-in-python/

Comment: A list with dictionaries - that is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the data in your `dict`s never change, and you want the keys, then you should opt for using [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)s.

You'll need to convert that nested `list` into a `tuple` since lists are not hashable. Then you can take your existing dictionaries and plop them into your namedtuple (or create them directly).

```
d1 = { 
   'test': 'baum',
   'alter': 0,
   'voegel': ('amsel')
}
d2 = { 
   'test': 'grosserbaum',
   'alter': 3,
   'voegel': ('meise')
}

from collections import namedtuple

Test = namedtuple("Test", "test alter voegel")

t1 = Test(**d1)
t2 = Test(**d2)

print(t1)            # Test(test='baum', alter=0, voegel='amsel')
print(t2)            # Test(test='grosserbaum', alter=3, voegel='meise')
print(set([t1, t2])) # {Test(test='grosserbaum', alter=3, voegel='meise'), Test(test='baum', alter=0, voegel='amsel')}
```

Now you can keep those namedtuples inside a `set` so that collection will contain only unique items! Also, namedtuples use less memory than a dict since it implements [`__slots__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots).